# Font color in Wordpress text editor

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating theme options on my WP theme. My text editor in Theme Options doesn't have font color option. How can I add that? I've searched around the web, but no luck. On regular pages and posts I can see the font color option.

I'm using Options framework. Here's the code snippet:

```
$options[] = array(
        'name' => __('Main text block', 'options_check'),
        'id' => 'main_text_editor',
        'type' => 'editor',
        'settings' => $wp_editor_settings );
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your are displaying a textbox and want the full editor. If so, use the following code to display an empty editor on your options page:

```
<?php

$content = '';
$editor_id = 'mycustomeditor';

wp_editor( $content, $editor_id );

?>
```

Read more about the possibilities in Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor

Comment: thanks, but it's not the issue. I've edited my question. Have a look